# jenkins Web Server Uses Plain-Text Form Based Authentication Qualys Vulnerability Scan

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

We have received few vulnerability alert with our Jenkins prod instance. Below is the vulnerability detected. Could you please let us know the cause for this and the steps to resolve the same.

Web Server Uses Plain-Text Form Based Authentication
Jenkins Version: v1.625.3.1

When we run scan using host url we are getting this alert,when we use LB URL we are getting different alerts.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated...Thanks in advance..First 2 results for LB URL scan and 3rd is HOST URL scan

[Scan Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rECt.png)

Comment: I think you should give a shot at locating the cause and solving the problem yourself. In other words, **what have you tried?**

Comment: We have SSL cert in place for LB so we cant incorporate SSL on host as well and we cant make any changes to iptable as per our organization standard...Instead of IP based routing we can try for local host based routing itseems